# 404 NOT_FOUND after migrating to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks version 2.0

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have followed the following links to migrate from V1 to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks version 2.0:

[Part 1](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating)

[Part 2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android)

I have deployed the backend module to google app engine but when I try to access an endpoint method such as a list e.g  https://projectid.appspot.com/_ah/api/theEndpoint/v1/file

I get the following error:

\n\n404 NOT_FOUND\n\n\n

## Error: NOT_FOUND

\n

Comment: If you go to `/_ah/api/explorer`, does it redirect to API Explorer?

Comment: @saiyr it does not for me, do you know any alternative for api explorer?